# Unable to remove id and label from hover_data in plotly express

Tags: python, plotly

For some reason I am unable to remove the id and label rows from my hover data in the sunburst chart I made. It thinks that "id" and "label" are supposed to be a column of the dataframe, but I'm referring to the id and label it generates when you hover over a wedge of the sunburst.

How am I supposed to remove the id and label from the hover? I'm recreating someone else's sunburst chart and they did the exact same thing as me to remove id and labels. For some reason it worked on their Python and not mine.

Here is my code:
*See the last line

```
ChallengeFig = px.sunburst(
    sunburst_df2,
    path = ['State','Unarmed',"Victim's gender"],
    color = "Victim's gender",
    color_discrete_map= {'Male': 'purple', 'Female':'greenyellow'},
    hover_data={"Victim's gender": False, "id":False, "labels":False}
)
```